# fillna of more than one column by using column numbers instead of names

Tags: pandas, nan, python-3.8, fillna

I am trying to fill all NaN values of a 50columns of dataframe with a fixed number. There are a lot of columns to be using them by theri names and they are always side by side.
Can I use a range of their column numbers for that?
Instead of

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].fillna(100)
```

to have sothing like

```
df[column 1: column 50] = df[column 1: column 50].fillna(100)
```

additional question: can I easily spot the column number and the header of my dataframe?

Comment: What is wrong with `df = df.fillna(100)`?

Comment: Or are you looking for `df.iloc[:,1:50] = df.iloc[:,1:50].fillna(100)`?

Comment: @mozway df = df.fillna(100) will fill all nan of the DF , which I don't want. Only the nan of columns 1 till cll 50 I want to apply fillna

Comment: Thus the 2 solution proposed, the second one is what you want ;)

Comment: @mozway can you also tell me how to identify each column's number?

Comment: I don't understand the request, can you provide an example?

Comment: @mozway I have 125 columns , so I want to identify, which one is the first, second,third etc. 
Then I will use the loc function as you suggested. But now, to determine that I want to run df.iloc[:,1:50] = df.iloc[:,1:50].fillna(100) on columns 1 to 50, I had to count them one by one, and find that column_name = "Country" is the column number 50!
Hope it helps you understand

Comment: then why use `iloc`? If you want to slice by name use `loc` ;)

Comment: I provided examples of indexing / mixed indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reporting the answer that [mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16343464/mozway) correctly suggested in the comments (all creds to him)

The solution is simply

```
df.iloc[:,1:50] = df.iloc[:,1:50].fillna(100)
```

meaning that you want to select every row  `:` and columns between 1 and 50  `1:50`. Beware that selection is exclusive on the second index.

Answer (score 1):

Given your numerous questions, lets get an example:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0, np.nan], size=(4,10)),
                  columns=list(ascii_uppercase[:10]))

     A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J
0  0.0  NaN  NaN  0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  0.0  0.0  NaN  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  NaN
2  0.0  NaN  NaN  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.0
3  NaN  0.0  NaN  0.0  NaN  NaN  0.0  NaN  NaN  0.0
```

The goal is to fill columns 1 to 5 (included):

```
     A      B      C      D      E      F    G    H    I    J
0  0.0  100.0  100.0    0.0  100.0  100.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN    0.0    0.0  100.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  NaN
2  0.0  100.0  100.0    0.0    0.0  100.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.0
3  NaN    0.0  100.0    0.0  100.0  100.0  0.0  NaN  NaN  0.0
```

###### filling NaN only in columns 1 to 5 (included) using `iloc`:

```
df.iloc[:,1:5+1] = df.iloc[:,1:5+1].fillna(100)
```

###### same thing with names B->F using `loc`:

```
df.loc[:,'B':'F'] = df.loc[:,'B':'F'].fillna(100)
```

###### mixed position/label indexing using `loc`:

```
last = df.columns[5]
df.loc[:,'B':last] = df.loc[:,'B':last].fillna(100)
```

###### mixed position/label indexing using `iloc`:

```
last = df.columns.get_loc('F')+1
df.iloc[:,1:last] = df.iloc[:,1:last].fillna(100)
```